# Updates with non-ASCII characters not found

Tags: vb.net, telerik, firebird

I am using a Firebird database in my application. Using Telerik controls to use this database. My database has some non-ASCII characters like "Â«Dios de AmorÂ» Video Oficial HD"

When I place same values it runs correctly, but if I change this value this gives an error that row is not found.

```
obj.value = obj.value
db.SaveChanges()
```

This works,

```
obj.value = "my value"
db.SaveChanges()
```

This gives and error that the row is not found, this happens only when there are non-ASCII characters in obj otherwise this work as well.

Comment: What is 1) your connection character set, 2) the default database character set, 3) the DDL (including character sets) of the table?